# Checking Email Address for Optional Number

Tags: regex, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to use regex to validate email addresses, one of the rules for the email addresses is that they can have an optional number before the '@' sign.  However when the program gets to that evaluation the number is never optional.

I currently have:

```
Regex.IsMatch(user.EmailAddress, Regex.Escape(basicExpected) + @"^\d{1}?$" + "@email.com")
```

`basicExpected` is `string basicExpected = user.GivenName + "." + user.Surname;`

so the email address should be

> first.last{optional number}@email.com

As dumby data the two examples are:

- john.doe@live.ca
- john.doe2@live.ca

The second john doe gets a 2 because there are two people in Active Directory with the name John Doe so the number is the disguising difference between the two.  When the evaluation is ran john.doe@live.ca will be determined as incorrect due to the absence of a number

**Update:**
I made the blunder of reading `$` as `?` so the `\d?` is correct I just kept misreading.  I do apologize for my mistake and I thank you for persisting in finding the solution

Comment: Remove `^` and `$` anchors. `"\d?"` is enough. Also there is a period before `@`. It does't fit the format.

Comment: I can't think of an instance where `{1}` would be needed. The previous character/group would already have been matched once. @revo is correct about the anchors, those are suppose to match the start and end of your string.

Comment: @revo I switched to "\d?", but left the @, is it not required in asp?  While keeping the @ it doesn't work, trying without now.

Comment: @revo without the @ it's an unrecognized escaped sequence in Visual Studio

Comment: Please add a real email address (in format) with its corresponding compiled regex to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that your quantifier isn't indicating that the number is optional, it saying that it's lazy instead of greedy.

```
\d{1}? # this is incorrect
```

An optional single number in regex is simpler to construct. Try this:

```
\d? # this is preferable
```

Comment: Hrm, it looks like you and I wrote the exact same answer twice in a row at the exact same time, I'll delete mine :)

Comment: I've tried \d? and the evaluation will still return false with my dummy data which doesn't have a number.

Comment: Have you tried without the line anchors, (i.e. `^` and `$`)?

Comment: @wcarroll I apologize for your wasting time, your solution was correct I just kept reading `$` as `?`.  So I thought I was following your solution when I made a blunder, all is good now.  Thank you and sorry again.

Answer (score 0):

If i read right what i explained :

`first.last{optional number}@email.com` should be matched by

```
user.GivenName + "." + user.Surname + "^\d{1}?$" + ".@email.com"
```

I see some issues here :

- in `"^\d{1}?$"` : the `^` and `$` implies begin and end. You don't want that because you have other stuff around it.
- ".@email.com" : why the 1st dot `.` ?

**Conclusion:**

`"\d?"`  is what you want for the conditional number and removing the `.` before *@email.com* might help

Comment: So the `.` before `@email.com` was accidental, it has been removed now.  I am now using the `"\d?"` but to no avail, it still won't work.